# Default Prompt to first day of current month on OBIEE

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I have a Analysis created in OBIEE 11G, by default I want it to have the default values in: *is between* ***Calendar Date***  *[First day of current month] - [Yesterday]*. For the first day i use the following (but didn't work):

```
TIMESTAMPADD (SQL_TSI_DAY, (DAYOFMONTH (CURRENT_DATE) * -1) + 1, CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Are you implying that on a dashboard, you want a prompt to default to a certain in between value, on you want an analysis filter to default to a certain in between value?

Comment: I am kind of new to this OBIEE. I have a report (analysis) i created a Prompt for Calendar Date the Operator (is between), so what i want is for it to have default values: 1st date of current month -- Yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ChiHam!

First, I created an analysis and filtered for the desired date column as "is prompted" ("Canonical"."Date" in this example).

http://i58.tinypic.com/29vjqye.jpg

Then, I setup a Dashboard Prompt (I chose to put it on a dashboard page, but you should be able to simply go to the "Prompt" tab if you're only running the analysis. Use a column prompt, select the "is between" operator, and select "choice list" for user input. Now the tricky part! Open the options using the small plus sign at the bottom left. Select "SQL Results" for Choice List Values and insert this SQL (you will need to change "Table"."Date" and "Subject Area" to your own date column and subject area):

SELECT "Table."Date" FROM "Subject Area" UNION SELECT  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,-1,CURRENT_DATE)  FROM "Subject Area"

Now to set the defaults! Select "SQL Results" for Default Selection as well. Insert in the first text box the beginning of the month date using this SQL:

SELECT  TIMESTAMPADD (SQL_TSI_DAY, (DAYOFMONTH (CURRENT_DATE) * -1) + 1, CURRENT_DATE) FROM "Subject Area"

Insert yesterday's date using this SQL into the next text box:

SELECT  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,-1,CURRENT_DATE)  FROM "Subject Area"

http://i57.tinypic.com/294hpuv.jpg

Then I put both objects (Dashboard prompt and analysis) onto a dashboard page.

htt p://i57.tinypic.com/35i0opi.jpg (delete 'space' in link, sorry posting limitations)

The results were my dashboard prompt was defaulted to the correct dates as of today (5/24) and my analysis was already run based of the dates without having to hit apply because the analysis is set to "is prompted".

htt p://i58.tinypic.com/efs9pz.jpg (delete 'space' in link, sorry posting limitations)

Hope this answers your question!